# Jade templating in Meteor

Tags: meteor, pug

In the Meteor FAQs http://meteor.com/faq/how-do-i-package-a-new-templating-system there is some information about adding a different (than the default Handlebars) templating system. Jade is the only other example explicitly called out elsewhere in the docs.

So is somebody already working on Jade? If not, is it feasible for me to start? Or is it still too early? e.g. :

> The package API is rapidly changing and isn't documented, so you can't
>   make your own packages just yet. Coming soon.

I've been trying to love Handlebars in my current Ember.js project, but for me nothing is as elegant as Jade.

Comment: At the moment of writing this the question is still not answered (as I asked for: there is debergalis answer, but it lacks of some details).

Comment: https://github.com/denysonique/Meteor-jade-handlebars This will allow you to simply write your HTML/Handlebars in Jade

Comment: [Blade](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade) is a Jade-like templating language that fully supports [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) integration, although it is not yet a part of the Meteor core. Might want to check it out if you are looking for an alternative to Handlebars. - https://github.com/bminer/node-blade
- https://github.com/bminer/node-blade#meteor-support
- https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/wiki/Using-Blade-with-Meteor

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We would love to see Jade integration.  Use `packages/handlebars` as a template.

The basic strategy is to wire the output of the template engine into `Meteor.ui.render` which is how we implement live page updates.  As long as your template returns HTML, that'll work.  Any time a Jade template references a `Meteor.Collection` document or `Session` variable, Meteor will register that dependency so that knows to rerender the template when the data changes.

Even better, though, is to also use `Meteor.ui.chunk` and `Meteor.ui.listChunk`.  These will limit the amount of recalculation Meteor has to do when there's a change.  For example, if you are rendering a list of documents using `{{#each}}` in Handlebars-speak, there's no reason to recalculate the whole template when a new document enters the result set.  We just render one HTML chunk for the new document, and insert that right into the DOM.  That's `listChunk` in action.

So you'll likely find that instrumenting just `if`/`unless` and `for`/`each` in Jade gets you a long way there.

Just be aware, package development is not as documented as the other parts of the system.  So don't hesitate to ask more specific questions as you go.

Comment: Great thanks! My Javascript knowledge only goes so deep, but I should at least be able to get a good start. I'll be back with questions...

Comment: Keep me posted. I want to try out Meteor, but I am not sure how to integrate with Jade just yet. Jade keeps me from writing plain-old HTML. I always forget the end tag.  :)

Comment: Also, other people interested in this can checkout Blade. Blade is a Jade-like language that works in Meteor 0.3.6. https://github.com/bminer/node-blade

Answer (score 16):

### meteor >= 0.8.0

Using the [mquandalle:jade](https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/jade) package has been  [officially recommended](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/27/meteor-080-introducing-blaze).

### meteor <= 0.7.2

1. If you are **not** using CoffeeScript, you should check out [jade-handlebars](https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars). As of this writing, there is an issue where CoffeeScript template files seem to need to be wrapped inside a `Meteor.startup` function which caused other issues for me.
2. If you are using CoffeeScript, you should check out my [Cakefile](https://gist.github.com/4644690). The details are all in the description, but the short version is that it automatically adds/removes/updates html files alongside your jade files. I ended up adding `*.html` to my `.gitignore`, which only works if you are not mixing html and jade in the same project. It's a bit of a hack but so far it's working fine for me.

Comment: I would like to use jade-handlebars, but not without coffeescript, is this issue being tracked somewhere?

Comment: The closest issue is [#9](https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars/issues/9).

Comment: how does pre generating the .html files work when this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389766/meteor-js-use-external-script ?

Comment: My impression is you'd just pre-generate it to use regular handlebars in html (I'm doing this for slim with CodeKit on mac)

Answer (score 10):

Just publish my first meteor smart package on Atmosphere!

Use Jade+Handlebars instead of HTML+Handlebars

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/jade-handlebars

Answer (score 3):

Just got jade templating working with my Meteor projects! And it is actual jade not jade-handlebars or some half form of jade. It is great but it needs Meteor UI which is currently in a development release called blaze-rc1. So it does not work with Meteor 0.7 at the moment.

do 'mrt add jade'

&

Run your meteor project using 'mrt --release blaze-rc1'

https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/

If you have coffeescript and jade files in the same folder add _ to the beginning of the file name so it loads jade files before the coffeescript file, otherwise it will not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`mrt add jade`

in `client/views/templates/hello.jade` you could do something like this:

```
template(name="hello")
  h1 hello world!
  {{greeting}}

  input(type="button" value="click")
```

start you app with `mrt`