# Meteor with Slim instead of Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, meteor, slim-lang

As [Handelbars](http://handlebarsjs.com) is the default templating layer for [Meteor.js](http://meteor.com), is it readily possible to use [Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) instead?

If so (*meaning, without an extreme amount of hacking*) how would one integrate this?

UPDATE: looks like this may be starting to be a real possibility with OpalRB since we're seeing some promising effort such as https://github.com/marcandre/meteor-opal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slim is a Ruby based templating engine; bludgeoning that into Meteor is probably not worth the effort.  Take a look at [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) (a port of haml/slim style templating to JavaScript); it looks like there are beginnings of support for that:

[Jade templating in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104887/jade-templating-in-meteor)

Comment: Nice thanks for pointing that out as I'd not seen this before.