# Coffeescript in Jade-handlebars in meteor

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, pug

How do we write document level coffeescript in jade-handlebars ?? In jade file I used following

```
 template(name="hellow")
      :coffeescript
         alert('helloworld')
```

But it gives error. Help me out guys

ERROR

```
Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at module.exports.coffeescript (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/filters.js:93:14)
    at Object.Compiler.visitFilter (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:419:28)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:176:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:161:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitBlock (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:253:12)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:176:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:161:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitTag (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:390:12)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:176:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (/home/rohan/.meteorite/packages/jade-handlebars/jrhone/meteor-jade-handlebars/e442fecedeac64b81a0865e1b195a630181a3ee4/jade/lib/compiler.js:161:10)
```

Thank You in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get this to compile, I'm not sure it will do anything because of the way meteor dynamically injects elements into the body. For example if you add:

```
script(type='text/javascript') alert('hello!')
```

to your jade, or the equivalent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello!')</script>
```

to your html, it won't actually execute - at least it doesn't for me. I *think* this is because the body has already rendered before the script was injected onto the page.

That aside, I did get this to compile, but not using jade-handlebars. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104887/jade-templating-in-meteor/14541874#14541874).